# How to generate seeded random floats of at least 20 decimal places in python?

Tags: python, numpy, decimal, precision, mpmath

I would like to generate seeded random floats of at least 20 decimal places in the range of -1 to 1.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2000)
np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=2)
```

This is what I would do in the past, but my DOE research requires more precision.

I've looked in to mpmath and decimal modules in python

```
import mpmath
mpmath.mp.dps = 22
xis = (mpmath.rand() - mpmath.mpf(1), mpmath.rand())
```

This does not work because I could not find a way to seed `mpmath.mp.rand()`.

```
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

getcontext().prec = 20
xis = np.asarray([Decimal(f"{x}") x for x in np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=2)], dtype=np.float64)
```

Here, my floats are dependent on numpy, and has max to 16-7 decimal places.

How can I create random floats that have 20+ decimal places and are seedable?

Comment: "Up to" and "at least" are opposites. You should pick one.

Comment: Does your version of numpy support `float128`?

Comment: You missed a spot, and "or more" becomes unnecessary as well.

Comment: yes it supports float128. np.random.uniform(low=-1,high=1,size=2).astype(np.float128))?

Comment: nope .astype(np.float128) doesn't work with random

Comment: Don't use `astype(np.float128)` when you can generate directly with `uniform(..., dtype=float128)`

Comment: you mean np.random.uniform()? np.random.uniform doesn't have a parameter "dtype"..

Comment: You're right. I was thinking of the newer Generator interface. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you will need ~70 bits of precision to correctly store a number with 20 decimal digits. A `long double` (`float96` or `float128`) in IEEE754 format has either 80 or 106 bits of precision, both of which are adequate for the task.

Unfortunately, [`numpy.random.Generator.random`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.random.html) only supports `float32` and `float64`.

Based on the current python implementation of [`mpmath.rand`](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/mpmath/blob/c11db84b3237bd8fc6721f5a0c5d7c0c98a24dc1/mpmath/libmp/libmpf.py#L528), the source of randomness is just the standard library [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module, specifically [`random.getrandbits`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.getrandbits). You should be able to get reproducible results by calling the usual [`random.seed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed). Unfortunately, the state is global: there does not appear to be a mechanism to use individual [`random.Random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.Random) objects, e.g., for different threads.

Keep in mind that you need to set the **working** precision, which can be done in a context manager:

```
random.seed(my_seed)
with mp.workdps(22):
    data = [mp.rand() for _ in range(my_size)]
```

If you have a collection of scripts that are being imported as modules, a single call to `random.seed(my_seed)` in your main driver will suffice to initialize the entire program.

If you are calling scripts externally, e.g. via `os` or `subprocess`, you will want to put the same line in each script. It's safer to use an import guard at that point, so you can use the script both ways without thinking about it:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    random.seed(my_seed)
```

Comment: ill try it out!

Comment: would i use random.seed globally? i need to run 100 DOEs simulations and reproduce the random floats of at least 20 decimal places

Comment: rng.random(2,dtype=np.float128) "
TypeError: random() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'"

Comment: i also have troubles using the solution that uses mpmath from your examples. My DOEs scripts are split into many different functions from many different scripts and directories of which i import to a wrapper object and call from a main function in a main.py. I need to figure out how to set random.seed() globally across all my scripts and functions in 1 place in my main function in my main.py script

Comment: @pysolver33. I just read the docs a bit more carefully. Generator.random only supports float32 and float64, so while the message is weird, the error is not unexpected.

Comment: @pysolver33. I've updated the answer. Setting the global state will make the entire program have a deterministic stream. Only threads will really mess that up

Answer (score 2):

A naive approach: you could create random string literals in the requisite range and feed them to the `Decimal` constructor:

```
import random
from decimal import Decimal,getcontext
getcontext().prec = 20

def rand_decimal():
    s = ''.join(random.choice('0123456789') for _ in range(20))
    s = random.choice(['-','']) + '0.' + s
    return Decimal(s)

for _ in range(10): print(rand_decimal())
```

Typical output:

```
-0.83346823024126032930
-0.84557526920081542182
-0.82525161638966954542
0.19433739638125145525
-0.21238635133910933910
0.53423291362045018461
0.01119989426218875072
-0.60199160675918881160
-0.53317266699396870741
-0.16609409040022211062
```

Comment: How would i seed this approach?

Comment: @you would just seed the underlying random number generator, e.g. `random.seed(2021)`

Comment: i see~ i think i would end up doing it for both approaches for mpmath and decimal.Decimal